# How to display all of the oneOf schemas in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have an OpenAPI document where an endpoint uses `oneOf` for the request body (this endpoint has 2 possible different schemas). In Swagger UI, I can only see one of the schemas where the endpoint is displayed, which I understand is normal. How could I display the other schema or link it, so I can access it easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Schema** tab in Swagger UI displays all subschemas of `oneOf` and `anyOf` schemas:

[image]

To reflect the alternatives on the **Example Value** tab, you'll need to manually define multiple request body `examples`, one for each schema. This will add a dropdown to Swagger UI so that the users can switch between the examples.

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bar'
            examples:
              fooExample:
                summary: An example of Foo data
                value:
                  foo: hello
              barExample:
                summary: An example of Bar data
                value:
                  bar: 123
```

[image]

I think there was an existing feature request to generate multiple examples for `oneOf`/`anyOf` subschemas automatically, but I can't find it. Feel free to [submit](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues) a feature request yourself.

Comment: "_Here's the link for the issue/feature tracking: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803_" - [@kushal](/users/21575650/kushal)